# $\frac{n}{2}\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)dt$ converges uniformly to $f$ where $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

Suppose  $f$  is a continuous function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, and for each $n\in \Bbb N$ define $f_n:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ by $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{2}\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)dt$. It is clear that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise, by the continuity of $f$. But does $f_n$ converges to $f$ also uniformly? The answer would be positive if $f$ is uniformly continuous, but I can't see whether the answer is still positive in the general case.

Comment: have you tried f(t)=e^t?

Comment: I wonder if this is true with some conditions. For instance, maybe if $f(x) = O(p(x))$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ for some polynomial $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  can explicitly compute the value of this expression when $f(t)=e^{t}$ and see that the convergence is not uniform on $\mathbb R$.

Note that $e^{x} a_n$ can never tend to $0$ uniformly on $\mathbb  R$ for sequence of positive numbers $a_n$. In this example $f_n(x)-f(x)$ has this form.

PS: I just noticed that $f(t)=t^{k}$ is also a counter-example for every $k >2$.

Comment: I have $f_n(t)=t^2+1/(3n^2)$, so $f_n(t)-f(t)=1/(3n^2)$ and I think the convergence is uniform. Is my computation wrong?

Comment: You should get $f_n(x)-f(x)=\frac  x n$.  Please check your calculation again. @user302934

Comment: I'm getting $f_n(t)=t^2 + \frac{1}{3n^2}$, in which case it is uniform. See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+%28x-%281%2Fn%29%29+to+%28x%2B1%2Fn%29+t%5E2) and [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28n%2F2%29%286n%5E2x%5E2+%2B+2%29%281%2F%283n%5E3%29%29)

Comment: I have checked my calculations three times. I do it by hand and I think I have done it correctly.  @MathematicsStudent1122

Comment: Look again at the last two lines

Comment: The simplification from the second equality to the third is incorrect. The $\frac{3x}{n^2}$ terms cancel out. The $\frac{1}{n^3}$ do not cancel out. The third equality should in fact be $\frac{n}{6}(\frac{6x^2}{n} + \frac{2}{n^3})$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Sorry, I did make a mistake. But $e^{t}$ works. Can  you check it?

Answer (score 1):

A correct counterexample is $f(x)=e^x$. Note $$e^x - n/2(\exp(x+1/n)-\exp(x-1/n))=e^x(1-n/2(\exp(1/n) - \exp(-1/n)))$$

and $1 - n/2(\exp(1/n) - \exp(-1/n)) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Since $e^x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, the $N$ required to force $e^x(1-n/2(\exp(1/n) - \exp(-1/n)))<\epsilon$ for $n \geq N$ very much depends on $x$.